# Finding the equation of motion based on the diagram and its transfer function

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, laplace-transform, control-theory, classical-mechanics

I have a diagram that looks like below:

[image]

Description: By applying force p(t), point A is moving with displacement $y = asint$. $k_1$ and $k_2$ stand for the coefficients of the corresponding spring, and C stands for the coefficient of the damper. The friction between the surface and the object can be ignored.

The questions have three subquestions:

(1) Find the equation of motion

(2) Find the transfer function with $P(s)$ as output and $Y(s)$ as input

(3) Find the amplitude and phase of $p(t)$ when reach steady state

Now, I would like to find the equation of motion for the diagram and find its transfer function based on the equation as $G(s) =\dfrac{P(s)}{Y(s)}$.

As far as I know, the equation could be like this:

\begin{equation}
  m\dfrac{d^2x}{dt^2} + k_1x(t) + k_2x(t) + (\dfrac{1}{k_1} + \dfrac{1}{k_2})x(t) - C(\dfrac{dy}{dt} - \dfrac{dx}{dt}) = p(t) 
\end{equation}

The transfer function I am asked to find is to take $Y(s)$ as input and $P(s)$ as output and this seems to contradict what I know about this kind of equation of motion, and I am also confused with the $y = asint$ at point A.

I have tried to write out the equation I believe to be, but it does not make sense if I want to find the transfer function with the defined input and output. Actually, I think the $y = asint$ should also be listed in the equation, but I have no clue or idea about how should I put it into it.

Can anyone help me solve this equation of motion or point out what I missed?

Thank you for your help and advice.

(Note: To me, based on the instruction, I believe that p(t) should be input, however, the question demands that the p(t) be output and y(t) be input to find the transfer function of $G(s) = \dfrac{P(s)}{Y(s)}$ which looks a bit strange if I follow from the description of the question.)

Comment: what is your $x$ adnd $y$ different?? isn't force pulling on something that is rigidly attached to the mass? The way it drawn is confusing. The damping $C$ you show represents air damping. So it does not really affect that the force is pulling on mass and the connection is rigid. Other wise you need to find the relation betwee $y$ and $x$

Comment: I am not good at physics. Initially, I think the y and x are the distance from the balance point which I thought was the object, but it looks like I have misidentified the balance point in this case. Now, I think the balance point is A, but then I am curious about how to omit $x(t)$ in the equation.

Comment: Don't you have a units problem when adding a term like $k_1 x$ to a term like $x/(k_1 + k_2)$?

Comment: @Nasser Yes, sir. I once thought about finding the relation between y and x, but after some attempts, I found it to become more confusing. But, I will try to focus on the balance point A and rewrite the equation, and try to replace the x with y.

Comment: If you can find $y$ in terms of $x$, then you can solve it. Transfer function give relation between one output and one input. You can't have two outputs $y,x$ in same ode.

Comment: The drawing is quite different than what I have learned from control theory, and thus stuck at this point. By the way, why is C represents air damping in this case? Usually, it is written as something like $C\dfrac{dx}{dt}$ in an equation of motion.

Comment: @JohnBarber Sir, I am not sure if I will encounter a unit problem, but I will check later if this is wrong to write the connected spring coefficient.

Comment: Have a look at [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Series_and_parallel_springs) wikipedia article.

Comment: Well imaging the mass sitting in some medium which has viscosity for example.  $C$ represents the damping that result due to this medium vs. in vacuum.  Air also generates damping. So physically it can be anything that damps motion. May be mass is immersed in tank full of oil. It will have larger damping. They are all represented as force $C v(t)$  that opposes the motion. The damping does not have to be a physical damper as you have drawn it.

Comment: @JohnBarber Thank you, it looks like I did write the wrong way.

Comment: @Nasser Thank you for the comprehensive description regarding damping. I now have a brand new understanding of damping, it now does look like air damping and makes sense more.

Comment: If damping comes from air, the you only have one output $x$. So all what you have to do to find transfer function is just convert the ode to Laplace transform. And find the ratio of Y(s)/P(s).  (or if you want to keep notation consistent, use X(s)/P(s)), whatever you prefer to use. It is just the ratio of output to input but in Laplace domain.

Comment: Yes, if that is the case, things are getting easier. But I am yet not sure if the damping could be omitted since the instruction depicts "the viscosity coefficient of a damper".

Comment: No no, I never said you omit damping. The ode remains the same. But you only have on dependent variable $x(t)$ instead of two. So the ODE has $x(t)$ or $y(t)$ only. But not both, since they are the same.  The force pulls one something that is physically attached to mass. So it is the same distance, call $x(t)$ or $y(t)$ does not matter.

Comment: Thank you @Nasser. It looks like all you said is reasonable.

Yes, I have reviewed your comments several times, and you said since the force pulls the object that is physically attached to mass, thus the distance is the same, to some degree, I can comprehend this. 

Therefore, if I regard $x(t) = y(t)$ in this case, I can write 
$k_1y(t) + k_2y(t) + (\dfrac{1}{k_1} + \dfrac{1}{k_2})y(t) + m\dfrac{d^2y}{dt^2} - c\dfrac{dy}{dt} = p(t)$.

Then, apply Laplace transform to the equation:
$(k_1 + k_2 + \dfrac{k_1 + k_2}{k_1k_2} + ms^2 - cs)Y(s) = P(s)$

Comment: Since the transfer function I am asked is $G(s) = \dfrac{P(s)}{Y(s)}$, the final answer could be writtem as below:

$G(s) = \dfrac{(k_1 + k_2)(k_1k_2 + 1) + (mk_1k_2s^2 - ck_1k_2s)}{k_1k_2}$.

Happy to be notified if I have misunderstood any detail or notion, thank you!

Comment: The transfer function is the ratio OUTPUT over the INPUT (in Laplace domain). The output is always the solution to the ode but in Laplace domain. i.e. if your ode is $x''+x'+x=P(t)$ and the output is $X(s)$ and the input if $P(s)$. , hence $G(s)=\frac{X(s)}{P(s)}$ I am using $x(t)$ in place of your $y(t)$ since displacement is in $x$ direction. So using $x(t)$ is more natural.  But what letter is used does not matter.  So you have the transfer function upside down the way you wrote it above.

Comment: Yes, it should be output over the input. However, the question asked me to find the G(S) with P(s) as output and Y(s) as input..., so I wrote it upside down. This is really really weird to me, I was even wondering if this was intended or just a mistake description.

Comment: It looks like mistake in the problem. This definition of transfer function does not agree with anything that is standard. You can ask your professor for clarification. (Assuming this is a HW problem for a class).

Comment: OK, thank you for your help! I also think that is a mistake. But I am afraid that it probably cannot be clarified since this is not a HW problem.

Comment: You still have a units problem. You can't add a quantity like $k_1$ to a quantity like $1/k_1$. The effective overall spring constant for the three springs shown in the diagram should be $\left[{(k_1 + k_2)}^2 + k_1 k_2\right] / (k_1 + k_2)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have

$$
\cases{
(\dot y-\dot x)C = p\\
m \ddot x = -k x + (\dot y-\dot x)C
}
$$

with $k = \frac{(k_1+k_2)^2+k_1k_2}{k_1+k_2}$

then

$$
\cases{
s(\hat y(s)-\hat x(s))C = \hat p(s)\\
\left(ms^2+Cs+k\right)\hat x(s) = s C \hat y(s) 
}
$$

now as

$$
\hat x(s) = \frac{s C}{ms^2+Cs+k}\hat y(s)
$$

we have

$$
\frac{\hat p(s)}{\hat y(s)} = s\left(1-\frac{s C}{ms^2+Cs+k}\right)C
$$

Comment: You have a units problem. You can't add a quantity like $k_1$ to a quantity like $1/k_1$.

Comment: You are right! I will fix it ASAP.

Comment: The effective overall spring constant for the three springs shown in the diagram should be $\left[{(k_1 + k_2)}^2 + k_1 k_2\right] / (k_1 + k_2)$.

Comment: Thank you for your post! The equation of motion looks reasonable to me until now. I noticed that the first equation of the second equation systems has missed the coefficient $C$. Besides, the final transfer function seems to have a missing $s$.

Comment: Thanks for the warning. Now it is fixed.